# Store loading order

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

My code of App.js here:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'KP',
    appFolder: 'scripts/app',

    controllers: [
        'MainSearch', 'List'
    ],

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            items: {
                xtype: 'searchdata'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is :
I have model('List'),store('List'),view('List') and controller('List')  - all of this for my grid. In store('List') I called the service, which give to me some data.

I want to view my grid after the "MainSearch" form. So, I called "MainSearch" first. (in App.js). But, before the form "MainSearch" is displayed in my browser, the service in 'List' was called. I not understand why it happen.
(when  the 'List' controller is not included in App.js - all works fine)

The "List"'s 'Store' code:

```
Ext.define('KP.store.List', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'KP.model.List',          

    autoLoad: true,

    pageSize: 20,
    autoLoad: { start: 0, limit: 20 },


    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        limitParam: 'size',
        startParam: undefined,
        api: {

        read: '/adres/listls'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }     
    }

});
```

'List' controller code:

```
Ext.define('KP.controller.List', {

    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views: ['personAccount.List'],
    models: ['List'],
    stores: ['List'],

    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'list button[action=close]': {
                click: this.closeClick
            }
        });
    },

    //закрытие формы
    closeClick: function (button) {
        var win = button.up('window');
        win.close();
    }

});
```

My List View code:

```
Ext.define('KP.view.personAccount.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.list',

    autoScroll: true,
    modal: false,
    plain: false,
    autoShow: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me, {

            items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                                store: 'List',

                                forceFit: true,
                                columns: [
                                            ....
                                       ],

                                dockedItems: [
                                              {
                                                  xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                                                  store: 'List',
                                                  dock: 'bottom',                                                     
                                                  displayInfo: true
                                              }

                                            ]
                            }

                    ]
        });



        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It isn't really clear what you're asking, you'll need to post more information.

Comment: It is not at all clear. `This is problem` is the best part... which problem?

Comment: May be it is due to   initComponent: function () in Vew "List"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is disable `autoLoad` in your store. This way store will be initialized but it will not call your service to get data out. Later you will call `store.load()` in `afterrender` handler of your grid.

Comment: It's deffinately autoLoad in your store, use 
          autoLoad: false. 
You can also load the store in the initComponent of your grid.

Comment: It's seems true, but it is not help me( I added a View code, may be you have some idea?

Comment: I did! I also must delеte from my store this code : autoLoad: { start: 0, limit: 20 }. Thanks you for advice!